# Use the Watson Sentiment Add-on with Twilio java sdk

Tags: java, twilio

Hi I am looking to use the Watson Sentiment Add on seen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFYEFz5beAg. I interact with Twilio through the Java SDK and have been unable to find any resources on this. I also have analyzed the Message object and don't see an addons field or something similar to the node/python set up. Is this possible through Java?

Comment: using  <version>(7.0,7.9)</version> of the twilio.sdk

Comment: Have you [enabled the add-on in your console](https://www.twilio.com/console/add-ons)?

Comment: No I haven't but I would think that the java message object in twilio would have all the possible fields that could exist. I will add the add on and see though.

Comment: The add-on fields appear in an incoming HTTP request. The fields should be readable by the web framework you are using. That's not really part of the functionality of the SDK.

Comment: So, you should be able to enable the add-on, send a test message and observe the parameters being sent to your webhook URL.